# date+time picker for jsf

Tags: jsf, date, time, components, picker

Is there any ready-to-use component for JSF that allows to chose the Date + the Time of an event? All components I know only allow for date. adding time manually is tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [RichFaces calendar](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf) component allow you to choose both date and time.

You can test it [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf). After choosing a date, it allows you to choose the time.
Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: hi, Unfortunately the rich:calendar does not really support seconds (See JIRA #RF-5364), are there any alternatives?